# JavaScript RegEX explicit character matches only once

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that has the following constraints:

1. Contains only `[A-Z0-9.*]` characters
2. Is 1 to 15 characters in length
3. Must contain a `*` but only once.

Therefore, the following assertions:

- ABC.123 **invalid** (no stars)
- ABC.123* **valid** (star at end)
- *ABC.123 **valid** (star at beginning)
- ABC.*123 **valid** (star in the middle)
- *ABC.123* **invalid** (more than one star)

My goal was to only have a single expression. I could obviously have an expression that asserts the first two constraints: `[A-Z0-9.*]{1,15}` and then a second expression to assert the third constraint `\*{1}`.

Is it possible to have an expression that essentially validates the overall structure of a string input, but then rewinds and re-evaluates the string with another expression?

Comment: `{1}` does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a lookahead you can use this regex:

```
^(?=.{1,15}$)[A-Z0-9.]*\*[A-Z0-9.]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/swsLXl/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.{1,15}$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have 1 to 15 characters in input
- `[A-Z0-9.]*`: Match zero or more `[A-Z0-9.]` characters
- `\*`: Match an asterisk literally
- `[A-Z0-9.]*`: Match zero or more `[A-Z0-9.]` characters
- `$`: End

Comment: **Alternatively** you can also use this regex: `^(?=[^*]*\*[^*]*$)[A-Z0-9.*]{1,15}$`

Comment: That is pretty clever. I have needed similar things before but could not think of any way to do it, thank you!

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!